# Print all rows whose 2 columns are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have downloaded a dataset on international football results and I'm having a problem with visualizing one thing. The column names are the following:

date

home_team

away_team

home_score

away_score

tournament

city (where the match took place)

country (where the match took place)

neutral (TRUE if the match took place outside the home team country, FALSE otherwise.)

I'm trying to figure out the correlation between the score and when the match took place. For that I want to print out (and then count) all rows where:

- home_team == city and home_score > away_score
- away_team == city and away_score > home_score

Also, if you guys know how to combine that without making two separate conditions, it would be nice to know too!

If anybody is interested, the dataset is available here: https://www.kaggle.com/martj42/international-football-results-from-1872-to-2017

I have tried the following but it did not work

```
for row in df:
    if df['home_team'] == df['city'] and home_score > away_score:
        print (row)
```

## Here's my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('results.csv')
```

For some reason the True/False was bool values so I changed it so str

```
booleandf = df.select_dtypes(include=[bool])
df_str = {True: 'TRUE', False: 'FALSE'}

for column in booleandf:
    df['neutral'] = df['neutral'].map(df_str)
```

Print all rows where neutral == 'FALSE

```
df[df['neutral'].str.contains("FALSE")]
```

Error encountered: unexpected EOF while parsing

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this should get you the rows you want to visualise. Try it out

```
df.loc[(df['neutral']=="FALSE") & (df['home_score'] > df['away_score'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing `home_team` to `city` will not work, as one is a country and the other is a city within the country. Are you trying to solve the problem of figuring out a global score for a home/away match?

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this. Generally, if you are using a python loop on a pandas dataframe, you're doing it wrong. In this case, you can get the count you're looking for like this:

```
home_team_win_count = len(df[(df.home_team == df.country) & (df.home_score > df.away_score)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, following you be the code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('results.csv')
home_team_win_count = df[(df['neutral']) & (((df['city'] == df['home_team']) & (df['home_score'] > df['away_score'])) | ((df['city'] == df['away_team']) & (df['home_score'] < df['away_score'])))]
```

As per your details, your requirement is `df['neutral']` is a Bool Column as you said and you need only `True`. Then you need if `city` equals `home_team` then `home_team` scores higher than `away_team` and if `city` equals `away_team`, `away_team` scores higher.